# How to detect multiple monitors on a macbook and assign to buttons

Tags: java, swing, awt

to start off I will just say that I am new to java.

I want to create a simple Java app with a Jframe and some buttons which takes screenshots of any selected monitors.
What I use is a macbook and 2 monitors ( different resolutions, than the mac ). I will use action listeners for each buttons.
I searched the net and saw that the GraphicsEnvironment library could do this ( right now it detects all 3 monitors ).
So, how can I assign each monitor to buttons Screen1/2/3 ( probably Screen 1 will be the default monitor which is the mac ) 
And the functionality would be : if Screen 2 is selected, when clicking on Take Screenshot button, only monitor 2 will be captured.
Also, another newb question : what am i doing wrong for the i++ button ??

Below is the "empty" jframe created.

Thank you.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import static java.lang.String.*;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // Get local graphics environment
            GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();

            // Returns an array of all of the screen GraphicsDevice objects.
            GraphicsDevice[] devices = env.getScreenDevices();

            int numberOfScreens = devices.length;
            System.out.println("Number of available screens = " + numberOfScreens);
        } catch (HeadlessException e) {
            // We'll get here if no screen devices was found.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

// Jframe module
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ScreenShot");
        frame.setTitle("Screenshot");
        JLabel cadru1 = new JLabel("Step:");
        JTextField text1 = new JTextField("1");
        JButton plus1 = new JButton("+");
        JLabel cadru2 = new JLabel("SubStep:");
        JTextField text2 = new JTextField("1");
        JButton plus2 = new JButton("+");
        JButton scr1 = new JButton("Screen 1");
        JButton scr2 = new JButton("Screen 2");
        JButton scr3 = new JButton("Screen 3");
        JButton path = new JButton("Set Path");
        JButton Take = new JButton("Take ScreenShot");

        frame.add(cadru1);
        frame.add(text1);
        frame.add(plus1);
        frame.add(cadru2);
        frame.add(text2);
        frame.add(plus2);
        frame.add(scr1);
        frame.add(scr2);
        frame.add(scr3);
        frame.add(path);
        frame.add(Take);
        frame.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        Take.setForeground(Color.red);
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 3));
        frame.setSize(200, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        public void  actionPerformed(ActionEvent) {
            plus1++;
            cadru1.setText("1" + plus1  );
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not valid Java program. You can't `++` to a `JButton`. You can't declare a method in another method (like you're trying with `actionPerformed(ActionEvent)`). If you want buttons do something, assign listeners to them.

Comment: Ok, so just for the first part, how can I assign the number of displays to a checkbox, something like if ( checkbox 1 is clicked -- do this for display #1, etc ) ?